# codeigniter insert many images name into database

Tags: php, mysql, image, codeigniter, insert

I am build uploader images and store it into database, I already can upload many images to folder, but I can't insert all images name that uploaded, and I don't know how to insert into database, first I have put commend on my code below when error occur, second I don't know the query to put it in database if the image count is different e.g 1-10 images, last question, if I do query "SELECT id..." and I want to return it, is there method to return it into string or int? If I use row() it will return stdClass object. please help me, 
below is my code:

controller :

```
$this->load->library("myupload", "form_validation");
        $this->load->model("testModel");
        $barangImage = array();

        if($this->input->post("formSubmit")) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("nama", "Nama", "required|trim");

            if($this->form_validation->run()) {
                $insertData = array(
                    "nama" => $this->input->post("nama")
                );
                if($id = $this->testModel->add($insertData)) {

                    //print_r($id);

                    if(isset($_FILES) && $image = $this->myupload->uploadFile($_FILES)) {
                        //$image here is already fill with all images name

                        if(isset($image["error"]) && $image["error"]) {
                            echo $image["error"];
                        }else {
                            foreach($image as $img) {
                                $barangImage = array(
                                        "gambar" => $img,
                                        "barangid" => $id
                                );

                            }
                            //but when i put into barangImage,
                            //it only stored last image name
                            print_r($barangImage);
                            //output `Array ( [gambar] => 2.JPG [barangid] => Array ( [id] => 52 ) )`
                        }
                    }

                    if($id = $this->testModel->add_images($barangImage)) {
                        echo "SUCCESS !!!";
                    }else {
                        echo "FAIL INSERT IMAGES!!!";
                    }
                }else {
                    echo "FAIL INSERT DATA NAMA";
                }
            }else {
                echo "FAIL VALIDASI RUN";
            }
        }
```

model :

```
public function add($newData){
        $this->db->insert("cobabarang", $newData);

        $nama = $newData["nama"];
        $id = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM cobabarang WHERE nama = \"$nama\"");

        return $id->row_array();
    }

    public function add_images($newImage) {

        //$this->db->insert("cobagambar", $newImage);

        $id = $newImage["barangid"]["id"];
        $gambar = $newImage["gambar"];

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO cobagambar(barangid, gambar1) VALUES($id, \"$gambar\")");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an error here:

```
foreach($image as $img) 
{
    $barangImage = array(
         "gambar" => $img,
         "barangid" => $id
    );    
}
```

change the `$barangImage` to `$barangImage[]`

when you put the images into database i suggest that using `json_encode($barangImage)`, and then `json_decode($images-json-string)` when you going to use the images.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your `foreach` loop

```
  foreach($image as $img) {
      $barangImage = array(
        "gambar" => $img  //might be img['img'] I guess $img is again an array...you hvae to check that 
        "barangid" => $id  //might be $img['id']check on this too..will be $img['id'] I guess
      );

   }
```

My guess is that `$img` is again an array with some keys. You really need to check on that And you can directly call the insert function in that `foreach` loop itself like this,

```
  foreach($image as $img) {
      $barangImage = array(
        "gambar1" => $img['img'], //I guess $img is again an array...you hvae to check that 
        "barangid" => $img['id'] //check on this too..will be $img['id'] I guess
      );
          $id = $this->testModel->add_images($barangImage));
   }
```

**NOTE:** The `keys` in your array `barangImage` must be column name in the table. i.e

```
gambar1 and barangid will be your column names. so you can directly use codeIgniter's active records.
```

Just change your `add_images` function

```
   public function add_images($newImage) {

    $this->db->insert("cobagambar", $newImage);

}
```